# How can i show loading spinner or text inside Select input in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Select or dropdown which will get loaded when the user clicks on the down arrow for the first time. And while the data is loading, we want to show the spinner or loading text

Here is the code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Cohort</mat-label>
    <mat-select disableRipple formControlName="form" (opened)="getData()">
      <div *ngIf="isLoading"><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></div>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let c of names" value={{c.id}}>{{c.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>  
</mat-form-field>

isLoading: boolean;
names: any;
getData(){
    if(this.names== null)
    {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.Service.getAll()
        .subscribe({
          next:(res)=>{
            this.names= res;
          },
          error:()=>{
            alert("Error while getting")
          }
        })
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use (click) instead of (opened) it will do what you want.

So the result should be

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Cohort</mat-label>
    <mat-select disableRipple formControlName="form" (click)="getData()">
      <div *ngIf="isLoading"><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></div>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let c of names" value={{c.id}}>{{c.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>  
</mat-form-field>

isLoading: boolean;
names: any;
getData(){
    if(this.names== null)
    {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.Service.getAll()
        .subscribe({
          next:(res)=>{
            this.names= res;
          },
          error:()=>{
            alert("Error while getting")
          }
        })
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: can you explain what happens exactly?